# How to create a category that's counting on the object conforming to a certain protocol?

Tags: objective-c, xcode4.5

Most of my tableView have a constant  table row height. That table height can be changed but only on design time. I don't feel like encoding that table row height twice.

So I do something like this:

```
@interface UIViewController (cellHeightofFirstRowForTable) <UITableViewDataSource>


@end

#import "UIViewController+cellHeightofFirstRowForTable.h"

@implementation UIViewController (cellHeightofFirstRowForTable)
-(CGFloat) cellHeightForTable: (UITableView *) tableView
{
    cellHeight= [self tableView:tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0]];
}
@end
```

Basically the first time table height is asked, I would like to compute it once, store it in a static variable and then simply use that value.

I got this compile error:

```
 No visible @interface for 'UIViewController' declares the selector 'tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:'
```

But hei, I already specify in the interface that this is a protocol for UIViewController that conform to UITableViewDataSource delegate.

So what's the catch?

Should I just copy the codes?

Note: By now I already know that the design is stupid. The question stays though for future use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of what sensible instincts might tell you, `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` is part of `UITableViewDelegate`, not `UITableViewDataSource`. It's also flagged as `@optional` so even if you did declare a `UIViewController` category that implemented that protocol, that wouldn't actually guarantee that the method is implemented.

Comment: Given that the in virtually 100% case of the time we always set UITableViewDelegate and UITableViewDataSource delegate to the same object, I wonder why apple bother separating them? Oh well....

Comment: Because the delegate is what handles interactions, while the data source is just that.  They can be and sometimes are separate objects - think of it as controller vs model.